Angular - Poplating signals based on a signal change and the result of an http call
I have a multi-tenant application where the user is allowed to select the current tenant. When the user selects a new tenant the application stores the selected tenant as a signal in a service to keep application state.
As a secondary reaction when the tenant is changed I need to make an http call to get a list of permissions that the user has been assigned in relation to the selected tenant. I would also like this list of permissions to be a signal in a service to maintain application state.
What are the best practices around populating a signal when another signal changes when and http call is necessary to retrieve the data that will eventually be used for another signal? How do I go about accomplishing this?

Please check out the an async computed: https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/derived-async/ but please be aware of race conditions.

I don't think it would be easily done using signals, manipulating signals in a non declarative way may be a sign that we are acting outside of best practices.
I think that using RxJS Subjects would be more appropriate in this situation.
